# Subprocess call failed to parse argument (kill function) Python

Tags: python, linux, parsing, subprocess, kill

Hello I want to use linux command in my python code, I'm using subprocess function but I get error:

```
kill: failed to parse argument: '$(jobs -p)'
```

linux command :

```
sudo kill -9 $(jobs -p)
```

python subprocess code :

```
subprocess.call(['sudo', 'kill', '-9', "$(jobs -p)"])
```

what i'm doing wrong ?

Comment: `'$(jobs -p)'` it will be treated as string and not evaluted

Comment: use `shell=True` if you want to evaluate your last arg

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre but it will work for whole command not just for last arg yea ?

Comment: yes that will work. Try it.

Comment: When I use shell=True it act like I will run just `kill` without any args